# Adding an introductory loading image

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, preloader

I would like to add **one time** pre-loading image in a wordpress site, when someone clicks the image, the homepage shows after that. This should happen only once with the viewers first visit. How can I achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: you can check for a cookie; if it's not there, display the loader, and then place a cookie; otherwise the visitor is not a first timer, so don't show the loader. all can be done in JavaScript but makes more sense to do it on the server side.

Comment: that directs the idea in the right manner. I will try to have it work. Let me see what can be done from the server side. Thanks!